# API Laravel Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm new to Laravel and the API. I do authorization on the site using Laravel sanctum. Authorized users have access to the largest number of routes, but if there is no token in the header or it does not match the token of the authorized user, then I get the error specified below. I'm not sure, but it seems that sanctum should send the page to the client with the 403 error code itself.

ApplicationController (The same thing happens with the other methods in this controller and others):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ApplicationCreateRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Application;
use App\Models\Status;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ApplicationController extends Controller {
    public function show() {
        return response()->json(Application::query()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get(), 200);
    }

    public function store(ApplicationCreateRequest $request) {
        $application                = new Application();
        $application->user_id       = Auth::id();
        $application->status_id     = 1;
        $application->description   = $request->get('description');
        if (!$application->save()) {
            return response()->json(['message'=>'Заявка не отправлена'], 422);
        }
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Заявка создана'], 200);
    }

    public function delete(Application $application) {
        if (!$application) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Такой заявки нет'], 404);
        }

        if ($application->user_id == Auth::id()) {
            if ($application->delete()) {
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Заявка удалена'], 200);
            }
        }
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Вы не можете удалить чужую заявку'], 403);
    }
}
```

AuthController:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ApplicationCreateRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Application;
use App\Models\Status;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ApplicationController extends Controller
{
    public function show() {
        return response()->json(Application::query()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get(), 200);
    }

    public function store(ApplicationCreateRequest $request) {
        $application                = new Application();
        $application->user_id       = Auth::id();
        $application->status_id     = 1;
        $application->description   = $request->get('description');
        if (!$application->save()) {
            return response()->json(['message'=>'Заявка не отправлена'], 422);
        }
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Заявка создана'], 200);
    }

    public function delete(Application $application) {
        if (!$application) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Такой заявки нет'], 404);
        }

        if ($application->user_id == Auth::id()) {
            if ($application->delete()) {
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Заявка удалена'], 200);
            }
        }
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Вы не можете удалить чужую заявку'], 403);
    }
}
```

api.php

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ReviewController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Http\Requests\UserLoginRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('user', [AdminController::class, 'show'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    Route::post('userUpdate/{user}', [AdminController::class, 'update'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    Route::post('userStore', [AdminController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    Route::post('userDelete/{user}', [AdminController::class, 'delete'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    Route::post('applicationUpdate/{application}', [AdminController::class, 'updateStatus'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    Route::post('applicationDeleteAdmin/{application}', [AdminController::class, 'deleteApplication'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
});

Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('authStore', [AuthController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('authLogout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::get('application', [ApplicationController::class, 'show'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('applicationStore', [ApplicationController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('applicationDelete/{application}', [ApplicationController::class, 'delete'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::get('review', [ReviewController::class, 'showReview']);
Route::post('reviewStore', [ReviewController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('reviewDelete/{review}', [ReviewController::class, 'deleteReview'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('reviewUpdate/{id}', [ReviewController::class, 'updateReview'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::post('reviewRatingStore/{review}', [ReviewController::class, 'storeEstimation'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('reviewRatingDelete/{reviewRating}', [ReviewController::class, 'deleteEstimation'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::get('reviewRating', [ReviewController::class, 'showReviewRating']);
```

Kernel.php

```php
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;

'api' => [
            EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController] does not exist. in file C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 832
> #0 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(712): Illuminate\Container\Container->build()
> #1 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(841): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()
> #2 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(651): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve()
> #3 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(826): Illuminate\Container\Container->make()
> #4 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(268): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()
> #5 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(1019): Illuminate\Routing\Route->getController()
> #6 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(980): Illuminate\Routing\Route->controllerMiddleware()
> #7 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(710): Illuminate\Routing\Route->gatherMiddleware()
> #8 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(686): Illuminate\Routing\Router->gatherRouteMiddleware()
> #9 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(670): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
> #10 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(636): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute()
> #11 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(625): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute()
> #12 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch()
> #13 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}()
> #14 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}()
> #15 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle()
> #16 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}()
> #17 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle()
> #18 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}()
> #19 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle()
> #20 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}()
> #21 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
> #22 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\fruitcake\laravel-cors\src\HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}()
> #23 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle()
> #24 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}()
> #25 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle()
> #26 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}()
> #27 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
> #28 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
> #29 C:\OpenServer\domains\ITR\index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle()
> #30 {main}

Comment: Please share the stack trace as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to do this. I will be glad if you tell me

Comment: Have you enabled the Debug option in laravel?

Comment: Goto your `.env` file and set `APP_DEBUG` to true.

Comment: It's on. I shared the complete error. Hope this is something that helps

Comment: Which Laravel version you are using? can you run the following command and try again? php artisan route:clear

Comment: I am using the 8 version of laravel. Executed the php artisan route:clear and route:cache commands, just in case. Nothing has changed

Comment: clear your config cache using `php artisan config:cache ` and then try again. 

Ps. You've to stop your artisan server first and then run the command.

Comment: It didn't help. I also tried php artisan config: cache and optimization